# Trouble saving matplotlib animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to make an animated heatmap.  I have data in a text file (rs_h) with 3 columns - x, y, z; i'm using scatterplot to make a simple heatmap, and then using the animation package to update the heatmap over time

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

data = pd.read_table('rs_h', header=None, sep=r"\s*")

frames = np.array_split(data, 9)

def main():
    numframes = 9
    numpoints = 75

    x, y, c = np.random.random((3, numpoints))

    fig = plt.figure()
    scat = plt.scatter(x, y, c=c)#, s=100)

    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, frames=xrange(numframes), 
                              interval = 5)
    #ani.save("movie.avi", codec='avi')
    plt.show()

def update_plot(i):
    frame = frames[i]
    scat = plt.scatter(frame[0], frame[1], c=frame[2])
    return scat,

main()
```

I'm having no trouble getting the animated heatmap; however, i run into an issue when i try to save the animation

```
/Users/Arjun/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py:695: UserWarning: MovieWriter ffmpeg unavailable
  warnings.warn("MovieWriter %s unavailable" % writer)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "heat_ani.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "heat_ani.py", line 21, in main
    ani.save("movie.avi", codec='avi')
  File "/Users/Arjun/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 712, in save
    with writer.saving(self._fig, filename, dpi):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'saving'
```

Anyone know what the issue is and how to get around it?

EDIT:  The issue was that i didn't have ffmpeg installed.  A simple brew install allowed the code to work

Comment: I have the same problem: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py:1218: UserWarning: MovieWriter ffmpeg unavailable
  warnings.warn("MovieWriter %s unavailable" % writer)
even though I have installed ffmpeg properly.

Answer (score 11):

I found a [solution for Linux](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/jrjohansson/scientific-python-lectures/blob/master/Lecture-4-Matplotlib.ipynb). Basically you need ffmpeg library or libav-tools

Open terminal and type as root

```
apt-get install ffmpeg
```

or

```
apt-get install libav-tools
```

Hope it might help.

Comment: This worked for me:  https://tecadmin.net/install-ffmpeg-on-linux/

Comment: For people having this trouble in 2020, the command is: __apt-get install ffmpeg:i386__