# Saving a matplotlib animation in Linux

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib

I'm having a problem saving a matplotlib animation. When I execute the following test script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_ylim([0,11])
ax.set_xlim([0,100])

u, v, ims = [], [], []
u.append(0)
v.append(10)
for i in range(100):
    u.append(i+1)
    v.append(10)
    ims.append(ax.plot(u, v, 'b-', linewidth=3.))

im_ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=50, repeat_delay=3000,
    blit=True) 

im_ani.save('c.mp4')
```

I get the following error:

```
im_ani.save('c.mp4')   
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/animation.py", line 712, in save
    with writer.saving(self._fig, filename, dpi):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'saving'
```

Now according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815717/trouble-saving-matplotlib-animation), I need to install either ffmpeg or libav-tools. I tried this and found ffmpeg was not available, however libav-tools did seem to install properly. However, when I executed my script again, I still got the same error as before.

I also (following the advice of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856990/cant-save-matplotlib-animation) answer) tried doing

```
mywriter = animation.FFMpegWriter()
anim.save('mymovie.mp4',writer=mywriter)
```

but that didn't work either! It resulted in the following error:

```
  File "anitest.py", line 22, in <module>
    im_ani.save('mymovie.mp4',writer=mywriter)    
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/animation.py", line 712, in save
    with writer.saving(self._fig, filename, dpi):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/animation.py", line 169, in saving
    self.setup(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/animation.py", line 159, in setup
    self._run()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/animation.py", line 186, in _run
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any help here would be much appreciated. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks!

Comment: The first error you are seeing is caused by [this bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2651) in matplotlib. It was fixed in v1.4.0, so you should probably consider updating.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *"ffmpeg was not available"* - did you try `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`?

Comment: Hi, yes I did `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg` and got `Package ffmpeg is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ffmpeg' has no installation candidate
`

Comment: How do I go about updating matplotlib? I tried `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib` and it said that matplotlib is already the latest version.

Comment: Updating matplotlib won't solve this particular problem - it will just mean that you get a more informative error message. It seems that `ffmpeg` was [removed from the official repositories in 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/a/432585/185188), but you can install it by adding [this unofficial PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media).

Comment: If you decide that you do want to update matplotlib, I suggest you set up a separate [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) so that you don't have to mess with the system-wide version in `/usr/lib`. Installing the backend dependencies inside a virtualenv can be a bit fiddly - see [here](http://matplotlib.org/faq/virtualenv_faq.html?highlight=virtualenv) for more info.

Comment: Christ this is more complicated than I thought it would be. I can't believe it's this awkward to fix - I'm using the most widely used python plotting library on the most widely used linux distro. It's not like I'm  wanting to do something obscure. I'll give this stuff a read

Comment: You can partly blame the Ubuntu maintainers for dropping `ffmpeg` from the official repos :-) As I said, updating matplotlib is purely optional - the simplest solution would probably be just to add that PPA and install `ffmpeg` from it.

Comment: Thanks! I added the ppa and installed ffmpeg from it :)  Everything works fine now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We arrived at a solution in the comments above. To summarise:

- The reason for that rather cryptic error message:

  ```
  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'saving'
  ```

  is [this bug in matplotlib](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2651) which was fixed in version 1.4.0 ([also mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20137792/1461210)).
- However, updating matplotlib to 1.4.0 or newer will *not* address the root cause of the problem, which is simply that `ffmpeg` is not installed ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24815717/1461210)).
- OP was having difficulty installing `ffmpeg` because it was [dropped from the official Ubuntu repositories in version 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/432585/185188) (it was reinstated in Ubuntu 15.04). One work-around for those still using older versions of Ubuntu is to add [this unofficial PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media):

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade   # recommended on first use
  sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
  ```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Make sure you using matplotlib V1.4 or higher

```
python -c 'import matplotlib;print matplotlib.__version__'
```

**2a)** Try to install `ffmpeg`, 
 on 14.04 probably you will fail.
if so, go to *2b)*

**2b)** then install libav-tools:

```
 sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

and use this clause to save animation

```
anim.save('image.mp4', fps=20, writer="avconv", codec="libx264")
```